# To grep 20 characters after and before match

Tags: grep, osx

I have the problem that I get too much information after the match for

```
grep -RnisI --color=auto "pseudomonas" *
```

I want to get only like 20 characters or 10 words after and before the match.

**What is the right tool to do such a thing?**

Comment: Your set of options is a bit odd when complaining about too much information.  You want one line _after_ and _before_ your match displayed (`-A1` and `-B1` resp.), but it's too much?  Where exactly do you want your output cropped?

Comment: Can you give an example input and the output that you are expecting?

Comment: I've altered the command, I test in Ubuntu 13.10, let me know if it works for you.  I have a grep option and an egrep option

Comment: See also [Context of the matching regular expression](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/140620/22565)

Answer (score 31, accepted):

```
cat file.txt | grep -o -P '.{0,20}string.{0,20}'
```

This should do it for you

Update:

If you don't want to cat, you can just use the grep with the file as a parameter:

```
grep -o -P '.{0,20}pseudomonas.{0,20}' FileName.html
```

Also, The -P uses Perl Regex, which the man pages says is experimental, if you want to avoid that flag, you could just use egrep instead:

```
grep -Eo '.{0,20}yourstring.{0,20}' yourtestfile.txt
```

Comment: What an ugly test file you have ;)

Comment: The rest of the file is actually really useful, that is part of a multi-line comment in the middle of a Scheme that had to be excluded without breaking our parser, it was just a good line to try it with.

Comment: Since its one of my files, its set to 755, but I can see how cat might not be ideal for an HTML file, you can try passing the file name to grep as a parameter, see my edit.

Comment: I mean by 777 files that you have 777 copies of different files, not the chown thing. I run $$$ egrep -o '.{0,20}pseudomonas.{0,20}'  * $$$. The command stays there infinity and does nothing. This then again seems to work $$$egrep -ori '.{0,20}pseudomonas.{0,20}' *$$$. The same with recursion and case-insetitive. However, it is very slow. I think it should not be that slow. Grep was considerable faster.

Comment: if catting doesn't work, you can always just put it into a file by adding `> results.txt` to the end of your command, but it won't tell you which file you found it in.

Answer (score 4):

```
pcregrep -MnirIso '(?s).{0,20}pseudomonas.{0,20}' . |
  grep --color -e '^' -e pseudomonas
```

Assumes matches and their context don't overlap and that filenames don't contain `pseudomonas`.

Also note that the reported line numbers are those of the beginning of the context.