# Context of the matching regular expression

Tags: grep, regular-expression

I'm using `egrep` with the `-o` option in order to just get the matching part of the line, e.g.

```
cat /usr/share/dict/words | egrep -o '(aa|ii)'
```

Now I'd like to see some context of the match, i.e. a few characters on the left and on the right. One way to achieve this is by

```
cat /usr/share/dict/words | egrep -o '.{3}(aa|ii).{2}'
```

Is there a better (more efficient and elegant) way? (I've gone through the `egrep` commandline options but didn't find one for this purpose.)

Comment: See also [To grep 20 characters after and before match](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/121450/22565)

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas Thanks, it's the same question, but I'm looking for a better answer. ;)

Comment: If it is the same question, this kind of clarification might be better if asked in-comments on the original.

Comment: If the Q is a duplicate (it is), the other answers aren't good enough, and you can't find a way to make this a new question, the answer to "Is there a better way?" is *No*. @HalosGhost Adding a comment to an existing question looking for another answer is unlikely to solicit any response from anyone at all.

Comment: I'd say they're closely related but not duplicates (I answered both). The other one was looking at limiting the (multi-line) context offered by `grep -A/B/C` and was asking for color, file names and line numbers. This one is simpler as it only asks for context around a (or several) match within a line.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could do something like:

```
$ echo 'aabiicaa' | perl -lne '
   while (/aa|ii/g) {print substr($`,-3)."[$&]".substr($'\'',0,2)}'
[aa]bi
aab[ii]ca
iic[aa]
```